# scanf unknown number of integers, how to end loop?

Tags: c

In class I need to use `scanf` to get integers to work with. Problem is I do not know to end the `while` loop. I wait for `'\n'` in the code, but it is passing all tests. The program has to complete for grading.

How to make code work when input includes several `'\n'` in input and spacebars at the end of input.

All numbers are given with spacebar between.

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int numbers;
    char ch;
    int stop = 0;

    while(scanf("%d%c", &numbers, &ch))
    {
        if((ch == '\n') stop++;   

        #my_code      

        if (stop == 1) break;
    }
```

Comment: Consider starting with `while(1) { ...; if (something) { ...; break;} if (something_else) { ...; break; } ...; }` type of loop. If break is forbidden, then you can convert it to use flag variables or something once it works, as a separate step.

Comment: Then, it is unclear what is the format of your input data, so it is really hard to help you otherwise. Anyway, your while condition is clearly false. `scanf` does not return boolean suitable for condition. Here you want return value 2, indicating that both `numbers` and `ch` were successfully read (if not... you should probably just `return EXIT_FAILURE;` from main instead of trying to solve parse errors... see the alternative loop suggestion in above comment).

Comment: Maybe something like `while((scanf("%d", &num[i++]) == 1) && (i < SOME_NUMBER))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while(scanf("%d%c", &numbers, &ch)) { if((ch == '\n') ....` has a couple of problems.

1. If the line of input has only white-space like `"\n"` or `" \n"`, `scanf()` does not return until non-white-space is entered as all leading white-spaces are consumed by `"%d"`.
2. If space occurs after the `int`, the `"\n"` is not detected as in `"123 \n"`.
3. Non-white-space after the `int` is discarded as in `"123-456\n"` or `"123x456\n"`.

---

> how to end loop?

Look for the `'\n'`.  Do not let `"%d"` quietly consume it.

Usually using `fgets()` to read a *line* affords the more robust code, yet sticking with `scanf()` the goal is to examine leading white-space for the `'\n'`

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Get one `int`, as able from a partial line.
// Return status:
//   1: Success.
//   0: Unexpected non-numeric character encountered. It remains unread.
//   EOF: end of file or input error occurred.
//   '\n': End of line.
// Note: no guards against overflow.
int get_int(int *dest) {
  int ch;
  while (isspace((ch = fgetc(stdin)))) {
    if (ch == '\n') return '\n';
  }
  if (ch == EOF) return EOF;
  ungetc(ch, stdin);
  int scan_count = scanf("%d", dest);
  return scan_count;
}
```

Test code

```
int main(void) {
  unsigned int_count = 0;
  int scan_count;
  int value;
  while ((scan_count = get_int(&value)) == 1) {
    printf("%u: %d\n", ++int_count, value);
  }
  switch (scan_count) {
    case '\n': printf("Normal end of line.\n"); break;
    case EOF: printf("Normal EOF.\n"); break;
    case 0: printf("Offending character code %d encountered.\n", fgetc(stdin)); break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Potential tweak `if (ungetc(ch, stdin) != ch) /* handle error */` (but *de minimis*)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin True, yet `ungetc(ch, stdin);` failing after a `fgetc()` is rare and the error handling of it might as well be `/* nothing */` -  which is what was hidden-ly employed in code  with the `;`. ;-)  OR `if (ungetc(ch, stdin) != ch) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`.  Note: I expect `printf()` to more likely fail than this `ungetc(ch, stdin);`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin An axiom I've used is the correctness of code is proportional the times it is executed.  A trouble with `ungetc(ch, stdin)` error detection is how to test the handler?  IOWs, if code is not testable, such error handling its likely wrong in itself and best left uncoded until a test is possible.  I know you suggestiontion was light hearted, yet it evokes a deep coding conundrum - why test for something that  _theoretically_ occurs yet lacks a way to do so? Hmmm.  Perhaps a post is needed someplace??

Comment: Yep, it was definitely a stray thought of minimal consequence. And there really isn't a present category of return to handle the failure at that point. (other than an error message and returning some value to indicate an error other than end-of-read with `'\n'`) I've always wondered how probable that failure mode was, and just out of habit checked that the character got put back. (in fairness, I've never actually had that error thrown... but in the world of dings for lack of total validation, it's more habit than anything else...)

Comment: The wording in C standards has always been such (C11 7.21.7.10: *"One character of pushback is quaranteed"*, except at the beginning of a (binary) file) that almost all existing code requires an `ungetc()` following a non-EOF `fgetc()` to succeed. Since it is widely required in e.g. parsers, C libraries tend to be written to conform to that expectation.

Comment: Thank you. Used simpfilied version for my code. Found what the problem was - misunderstanding the terminal behavior. When I used file to input data, everthing worked fine. "while(scanf("%d%", &numbers,) != EOF)" or "while(scanf("%d%", &numbers,) == 1)" is easy solution for my problem