# How can I get input integers from user until he press enter by using eof?

Tags: c, input, int, scanf, eof

we start coding C and I cant solve my h.w because I dont know how to get input from the user (integers) until he press enter like 20 30 10 40 and after that the while done by using eof.
here is part of the code that doesnt work,

```
printf("Students, please enter heights!\n");
   while((scanf("%d",&height))!=EOF)
    {
        if(height>0)
        {
            avg_girls=avg_girls+height;
            counter_girls++;
        }

        else
        {
            avg_boys=avg_boys+height;
            counter_boys++;
        }  
    }
```

I getting into infinity loop
thanks you very much.

Comment: This will be much easier if you don't use `scanf`.  (Use `fgets` and `strtol` instead.)

Comment: thank you very much, but we started c like week ago and I think we should use scanf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scanf unknown number of integers, how to end loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52937192/scanf-unknown-number-of-integers-how-to-end-loop)

Comment: Are you sure you need to do what you are trying to do? What does the assignment say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a better way to accomplish reading an unknown number of integers from a line would be to read the entire line into a buffer of sufficient size and then step through the buffer using `strtol` (utilizing its `endptr` parameter to update your position in the buffer to `1-character` past the last value converted), you can use `scanf` and accomplish the same thing.

One approach for using `scanf` to read multiple integers from a line of input is simply to read each character and confirm it is not the `'\n'` character or `EOF`. If the character isn't a digit (or a `'-'` sign preceding a digit - [thanks Ajay Brahmakshatriya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2858773/ajay-brahmakshatriya)), then just go get the next character. If the character is a digit, put it back in `stdin` with `ungetc` and then call `scanf` and *validate the conversion* before updating either girls or boys average based on the sign of the input.

You could do something like the following:

```
    int height;

    fputs ("enter heights: ", stdout);

    while ((height = getchar()) != '\n' && height != EOF) {
        /* if not '-' and not digit, go read next char */
        if (height != '-' && !isdigit (height))
            continue;
        ungetc (height, stdin);     /* was digit, put it back in stdin */
        if (scanf ("%d", &height) == 1) {   /* now read with scanf */
            if (height > 0) {       /* postive val, add to girls */
                avg_girls += height;
                counter_girls++;
            }
            else {                  /* negative val, add to boys */
                avg_boys += height;
                counter_boys++;
            }
        }
    }
```

The `isspace()` macro is provided by the `ctype.h` header. If you cannot include other headers, then simply check whether `height` is a digit manually, e.g.

```
    if (height != '-' && (height < '0' || '9' < height))
        continue;
```

(remember you are reading *characters* with `getchar()`, so make the comparison against the ASCII characters for `'0'` and `'9'`)

Another alternative is to read the entire line of input into a buffer and then repeatedly call `sscanf` converting integers as you work through the buffer additionally utilizing the `"%n"` specifier to report the number of characters consumed by the call to `sscanf`. (e.g. using `"%d%n"` and providing a pointer to `int` to hold the value provided by `"%n"`) You can then keep a running total of the *offset* from the beginning of the buffer to add to your pointer to position `sscanf` for its next read.

Either way is fine, but reading a line-at-a-time presents many fewer pitfalls for the new C programmer to navigate than attempting to work with `scanf` and `stdin` itself.

Comment: thank you very much, you help me alot, can I ask another question about the solution ?

Comment: Since OP also needs to input negative integers too `if(!isdigit (height)) --> if(!isdigit(height) && height != '-')`

Comment: @Ofirlevy sure, if it's a follow-on, just leave a comment. I'll be by within an hour or so.

Answer (score -1):

You can use scanf and array to achieve this.

```
while (scanf("%d*[^\n]", &height[i++]) == 1 && i < height_len);
```

scanf will return the number of items correctly read.

Then process your heights.

Comment: This doesn't work and `%d` will always try to eat the linefeed before the number anyway.

Comment: Thanks, it should be "%d*[^\n]".

Comment: I tried [this](https://pastebin.com/E7u72WuH) snippet and it seems to work.