# How to read two lines with a random numbers count from input into two arrays

Tags: c, scanf

For example, input is:

```
12 23 32 41 45
22 11 43
```

lines end with `'\n'`,

I want to save the numbers to `a[]` and `b[]`;

```c
a[] = {12, 23, 32, 41, 45}
b[] = {22, 11, 43}
```

The point is, **I don't know how many** numbers are in each line.

If I know line1 ha `n` numbers, and line2 has `m` numbers, I will use `for` loop:

```c
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) scanf("%d", a+i);
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) scanf("%d", b+i);
```

Comment: Can you accept a number max for array length ?

Comment: If you care about line endings, then you either need to read one character at a time with `fgetc`, or read a line at a time with `fgets`.

Comment: Read characters until a new line is reached, if one isn't reached, resize your buffer? You'll want to use dynamic memory allocation probably.

Comment: A good function for reading a line at a time is `getline`, which was standardized in POSIX.1-2008. In comparision to `fgets`, it can read a line of arbitrary length into a dynamically allocated buffer. If you don't have the `getline` function, there are various standalone implementations of it, such as the one at https://github.com/ivanrad/getline .

Comment: You could use a `while` loop and some arbitrary input as break condition & dynamically alloc your input array(i think).

Comment: [scanf unknown number of integers, how to end loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52937192/2410359) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to continue using a `scanf` approach, I would recommend the negated scanset `%[^]` format specifier.

```c
scanf("%[^\n]", pointerToCharArray)
```

This should read in any number of characters up to **but not including** the character specified (which, in our case, is a newline). If you'd like to discard the newline, read it in as follows:

```c
scanf("%[^\n]\n", pointerToCharArray)
```

[More information about the negated scanset specifier](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

From this point, it is a simple matter to use [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) to tokenize the output of the scanf into number arrays.

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]\n", pointerToCharArray)` not only consumes a following newline, it waits for additional input consuming all other white-spaces.  `scanf()` then does not return until following non-whitespace detected or EOF.

Comment: As OP is concerned about "I DON'T KNOW how many number ", using `"%[^\n]"` without a width limit is fragile code.

Answer (score 0):

Let us use the non standard [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html),  a common library extension. [@Abbott](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53379386/how-read-two-lines-numbers-from-input-to-2-arrays-c-language-without-knowing-t#comment93634986_53379386) to read the *entire* line into allocated memory.

If an *array* is needed and its size determined at run-time, use a [variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99) available in C99 and optionally in C11.

Make a function to count and maybe save the numbers.  Use [`strto...()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) functions for robust parsing.

```
size_t count_longs(char *line, long *dest) {
  size_t count = 0;
  char *s = line;
  for (;;) {
    char *endptr;
    long num = strtol(s, &endptr, 10);
    if (s == endptr) {
      break;  /// no conversion
    }
    s = endptr;
    if (dest) {
      dest[count] = num;
    }
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Sample code snippet

```
  char *line = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  ssize_t nread = getline(&line, &len, stdin);  // read the whole line
  if (nread != -1) {
    // successful read

    long a[count_longs(line, NULL)];  // determine array size and use a 
    count_longs(line, a);             // 2nd pass: assign array elements. 

    nread = getline(&line, &len, stdin);
    if (nread != -1) {
      // successful read

      long b[count_longs(line, NULL)];
      count_longs(line, b);

      // Do something with a and b
    }
  }
  free(line);
  len = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that could potentially fit what OP asked for would be the code below.
The solution reads an unspecified number of integer values & stores them in `arr`. to break the loop/end input simply input a non-integer value. This could be further specified to search for a specific input etc.

```
int c = 0;
int *arr = NULL;
int *extArr = NULL;
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; scanf("%d", &c) == 1; i++)
{
    extArr = (int*)realloc(arr, (i+1) * sizeof(int)); 
    arr = extArr;
    arr[i] = c; 

}
free(arr);
```

I would, however personally go with a mix between the solution i provided & armitus answer(if i cant use `getline` or similar) since reallocating memory for every single int value seems redundant to me.

**Edit** Since there has been some question about the code i provided and how to best use it in order to fulfill the OP's question. The codesnippet was supposed to showcase how one might create his own scanf-style function for unspecified number of integer inputs reading one full array at a time(in that case the `free()` has to be omitted till one is done with the array(obviously).

Comment: I do see a functional problem.  `scanf("%d", &c)` will read through an end-of-line like any other white-space.  I'd expect OP's two lines of integers to end up in one `arr` here.

Comment: The idea was to use my codesnippet as a standalone function & then just call it n times for the number of array's required. i admittedly omitted those details from my answer.

Comment: Maybe i should've phrased that better. I did not mean n as in array length, but n as in number of array's read. Since the codesnippet can easily be packed inside a function and used as a sort of scanf-overload for array's

Answer (score 0):

The following code would be a bit complicated, but I think it's the easiest way to understand, only with small knowledgement of `char` pointers.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define ll long long

char* scan_str()
{
    char c, *res = (char*)malloc(1);
    int i = 0;
    while ((c = getc(stdin)) != '\n')
    {
        res[i++] = c;
        res = (char*)realloc(res, i+1);
    }
    res[i] = '\0';
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    //Input for the 1st array - A
    FILE* f1 = fopen("2lines.dat", "w");
    char* s = scan_str();
    fprintf(f1, "%s", s);
    fclose(f1);
    FILE* f2 = fopen("2lines.dat", "r");
    int c = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
        if (s[i] == ' ') c++;
    ll a[c];
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
        fscanf(f2, "%lld", a+i);
    fclose(f2);
    //Input for the 2nd array - B
    f1 = fopen("2lines.dat", "w");
    *s = scan_str();
    fprintf(f1, "%s", s);
    fclose(f1);
    f2 = fopen("2lines.dat", "r");
    c = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
        if (s[i] == ' ') c++;
    ll b[c];
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
        fscanf(f2, "%lld", b+i);
    fclose(f2);
    return 0;
}
```

But I don't know if defining arrays within the `main` function would be limited in memory storage, so more advices are really appreciated.

Comment: NOTE: You need to "clean" the string before inputting from the .dat file, by making sure that there's exactly 1 space character between each pair of numbers. Otherwise this function wouldn't work properly.