# How to read undefined number of integers from stdin line by line?

Tags: c, int, scanf, stdin

I need to read and store integers from standard input using C received in the following format: "35:27,5,10" There is an undefined number of integers on each line and an undefined number of lines. Ideally, I would like to have a loop inside of which I could use the values from the most recently scanned line to perform other tasks. How would I go about scanning and storing the integers in an array and then overwriting the array when scanning the next line, and so on until I hit EOF?

I presume I have to use a combination of scanf() and strtok(), but I can't seem to figure out how to. I have also tried to use getchar() but that only complicated things more.

Comment: just use scanf but pay attention to what comes after each integer, if it's '\n' that the end of the line,

Comment: [scanf unknown number of integers, how to end loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52939027/2410359) may be useful.

Comment: So, you really don't care about the undefined number of lines because you will treat each line separately.  You only need to know how many integers are available on each line and what they are.  Presumably, 32-bit (signed) `int` values are big enough for the number of integers on a single line — or do you need to cater for multiple gigabytes of data on a single line?  Are the values within range of `int` (32-bit signed integer) too?  Are there negative values?  Do you have any delimiters other than colon, comma and newline?  You haven't shown what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

This program reads a file of that format (on stdin) emitting an error if something unexpected is found.

```
//sumline.c  sum integers on each line.
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int sum=0;
  int rowcount=0;
  char buf[30]="";
  while(! feof(stdin) )
  { 
    int in;
    char sep[2];
    if((scanf("%1[^0-9-+]",sep)) && !feof(stdin))
    {
        fgets(buf,30,stdin);
        printf("unexpected %d char (%c,%30s)\n",sep[0],sep[0],buf);
        return 1;
    }
    if( ! scanf("%d",&in))
    {
        printf("malformed int\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if( feof(stdin) && rowcount == 0 )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    sum += in;
    if( ! scanf("%1[,:.\n]",sep) && !feof(stdin))
    {
        fgets(buf,30,stdin);
        printf("inexpected char %30s\n",buf);
        return 1;
    }
    else    
    {
      ++rowcount;
    }

    if( sep[0]=='\n' && rowcount )
    {
        printf("sum=%d\n",sum);
        sum=0;
        rowcount=0;
    }

    if( feof(stdin) && rowcount == 0 )
    {
        return 0;
    }
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm - leading  non-`'\n'` white-spaces cause `printf("unexpected ...` .  seems rigid yet compliant with OP's goals.

Comment: someone complained about scanf("%d" not checking for '\n' so I changed the order of the loop.  if a file is claime to have such and such format, it's a good idea to make sure it really does

Answer (score 0):

> I presume I have to use a combination of scanf() and strtok()

Use `fgets()` to read lines and `sscanf()` to scan the line read for integers:

```
#include <stddef.h>  // size_t
#include <stdlib.h>  // realloc(), free()
#include <stdio.h>   // fgets(), sscanf(), printf(), puts(), fputs()

int main(void)
{
    char line_buffer[100];          // a buffer for the current line
    int *values_buffer = NULL;      // pointer to memory to store the values in
    size_t values_buffer_size = 0;  // actual size of the value buffer

    // while a line can be read from stdin ...
    while (fgets(line_buffer, sizeof line_buffer / sizeof *line_buffer, stdin)) {
        size_t num_values = 0;    // to count the values we're able to extract
        char *pos = line_buffer;  // the current read-position inside line_buffer

        // try to extract integers from the line_buffer at position pos:
        for (int consumed = 0, value;
             sscanf(pos, "%d%*[^0123456789]%n", &value, &consumed) >= 1;
             pos += consumed)
        {
            // %*[^0123456789] discards a string not containing any digit
            // %n yields the number of characters consumed

            // if the value_buffer isn't big enough ...
            if (num_values >= values_buffer_size) {
                // resize it
                int *tmp = realloc(values_buffer, (num_values + 1) * sizeof *tmp);
                if (!tmp) {
                    fputs("Not enough memory. :(", stderr);
                    free(values_buffer);
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                // ... and update it's size
                values_buffer_size = num_values + 1;
                values_buffer = tmp;
            }

            // save the current value in value_buffer
            values_buffer[num_values++] = value;
        }

        // have fun with the values of the current line:
        if (num_values) {
            printf("Values: ");
            for (size_t i = 0; i < num_values; ++i)
                printf("%d ", values_buffer[i]);
            putchar('\n');
        } else puts("No values. :(\n");
    }

    // clean-up:
    free(values_buffer);

    if (ferror(stdin)) {
        fputs("An input error occured. :(\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else if (feof(stdin))
        puts("EOF reached.\n");
}
```

Comment: now if i enter `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001' as the first integer what happens?

Comment: scanf is not botthered by such long integers,  you are chopping the line up into several chunks using fgets.

Answer (score 0):

> I presume I have to use a combination of scanf() and strtok()

I'd presume otherwise:

- the user could enter an "almost infinite" amount of zeros before any number, or lots of whitespace, or lots of zeros after a decimal point, or.... This means that you can't expect (e.g.) to have all digits of a number in RAM at the same time; which implies that none of the functions C provides are usable.
- errors happen. When parsing text, unambiguous and descriptive feedback should be considered mandatory, regardless of whether the text came from a user (who needs to know why their text wasn't liked) or from a file or another computer (where a developer needs to be able to find/fix problems).

The best was to avoid both problems is with a state machine in a loop; like maybe:

```
int state = NEWLINE;
unsigned int lineNumber = 0;
unsigned int dataNumber;

while( ((c = getChar()) != EOF)) && (state != ERROR) ) {
    switch(state) {
        case NEWLINE:
            lineNumber++;
            if(isDigit(c) {
                number = c - '0';
                state = FIRST_NUMBER_STARTED;
                dataNumber = 1;
            } else {
                printf("ERROR: Character at start of line is not a valid decimal digit\n");
                state = ERROR;
            }
            break;
        case FIRST_NUMBER_STARTED:
            if(isDigit(c) {
                digit = c - '0';
                if(number > UINT_MAX/10) {
                    printf("ERROR: First number on line %u is too large\n", lineNumber);
                    state = ERROR;
                } else {
                    number *= 10;
                    if(number > UINT_MAX - digit) {
                        printf("ERROR: First number on line %u is too large\n", lineNumber);
                        state = ERROR;
                    } else {
                        number += digit;
                    }
                }
            } else if(c == ';') {
                state = COLON_FOUND;
            } else {
                printf("ERROR: Invalid character after first number on line\n");
                state = ERROR;
            }
            break;
        case COLON_FOUND:
            if(isDigit(c) {
                number = c - '0';
                state = DATA_NUMBER_STARTED;
            } else {
                printf("ERROR: Character at start of data not a valid decimal digit\n");
                state = ERROR;
            }
            break;
        case DATA_NUMBER_STARTED:
            if(isDigit(c) {
                digit = c - '0';
                if(number > UINT_MAX/10) {
                    printf("ERROR: Data number %u on line %u is too large\n", dataNumber, lineNumber);
                    state = ERROR;
                } else {
                    number *= 10;
                    if(number > UINT_MAX - digit) {
                        printf("ERROR: Data number %u on line %u is too large\n", dataNumber, lineNumber);
                        state = ERROR;
                    } else {
                        number += digit;
                    }
                }
            } else if(c == ',') {
                state = COMMA_FOUND;
            } else if(c == '\n') {
                state = NEW_LINE;
            } else {
                printf("ERROR: Invalid character after data number %u on line %u\n", dataNumber, lineNumber);
                state = ERROR;
            }
            break;
        case COMMA_FOUND:
            dataNumber++;

            if(isDigit(c) {
                number = c - '0';
                state = FIRST_NUMBER_STARTED;
            } else if(c == '\n') {
                printf("ERROR: Missing number after comma at end of line %u\n", lineNumber);
                state = ERROR;
            } else {
                printf("ERROR: Invalid character after comma (after data number %u) on line %u\n", dataNumber-1, lineNumber);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Note: Example code doesn't store any of data, and doesn't handle whitespace (or decimal points, or...) at all (you can add more code and new states for that), etc. Mostly; it's "very untested" code intended as an example only.